# Restarting EXAM tool throws error with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, illegalstateexception

I have installed and configured the EXAM tool on my laptop and it worked fine. However, when I closed the application and tried to reopen it, it says "An error has occurred.See the log file"

The log file gives the below error

```
    !SESSION 2019-09-09 12:14:54.592 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-09-09 12:14:55.209
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Can someone help me with this. I tried finding solutions around this problem, but the answers are not relevant in my case as I am not installing eclipse directly.

Comment: What "EXAM" tool is this?

Comment: @greg-449 EXAM is a graphical test development tool. You can find more information here http://www.exam-ta.de

Comment: Your Eclipse seems to be very old as it runs on Java 7 (more recent versions require Java 8). Can you reproduce this issue with the current version of Eclipse?

Comment: @howlger I haven't explicitly installed eclipse while installing the EXAM tool. So i am not sure about changing eclipse version here. I can however find few eclipse files in the EXAM configured folder. Is there any file where in I could change the eclipse version? Also this tool needed Java 1.8 and above. So i have  "openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)" installed. I have no clue from where it is picking 1.7

Comment: @NSP So EXAM is an Eclipse based application, right? You might try to start the EXAM `*.exe` file from the command line with the arguments `-data new_workspace`. If Java is not included, try to install Java 8 (e.g. from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)). Independently of whether the two things help, I recommend reporting the issue to the EXAM project.

Comment: @howlger Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to start it from the command line. I have already reported the issue in the EXAM project a month back, however the community there is not really active :(

Comment: @howlger tried to start it with another workspace, but still no luck

Comment: @NSP Does the installation contain Java (e.g. in the subfolder `jre`, or referenced in the `*.ini` file next to the `*.exe` file)? If not, try to run it with [Java 8](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Comment: @howlger yes it does have java 7 runtime in the jre folder

Comment: @NSP Since Java 7 is shipped with EXAM, there is not much you can do. The only thing I can think of is that EXAM can't write in the installation directory or in another used folder. This all looks very old and Windows has become more restrictive. You could try to reinstall EXAM into a new directory that has write permissions (and to be sure, without spaces in the path).